# Decision Split (or something else) for an AB Test in Journey Builder? Trying to find a solution

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, ab-testing

We have a project where customers are going to be purchasing products, but all products are unique. We have a certain list of products that we are going to provide an additional video within the onboarding/welcome journey in order to AB test retention and engagement.

We currently are trying to figure out a way to split out those who purchase a specific product we are testing in order to send them different content from the rest (there are upwards of 1,000 products we are testing).

We've had the thought of using decision split and attribute equals (insert product #), but since we can't separate them by commas and would have to use the "or" functionality, that would be unrealistic. We also thought through trying to link data extensions in contact builder, but we don't think that would work since the product data extension would not have contact data associated with it.

Is there a way to do lookup on product number and if the product number resides in a certain data extension then they go down a different path?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare your Entry Source Data Extension fields and data in advance in Automation Studio by creating an SQL Query Activity that would have a logic to check for the product(s) and then set a Group number, e.g.

```sql
SELECT
Id,
Product,

CASE
    WHEN Product = 'Apple' OR Product = 'Orange' OR Product = 'Banana' THEN 'Group_1'
    WHEN Product = 'Tomato' THEN 'Group_2'
    ELSE 'Group_3'
END AS Product_Group

FROM [Data_Extension]
```

That way, you would have a field that would be able to split your audience into groups before they would be pushed to the journey and simply send them to different paths by Decision Split that would be checking this new field "Product_Group".